# disable dhcp in initramfs

Tags: debian, networking, ip, initramfs

In Debian, how can I tell initramfs not to request an IP address via DHCP?  I'm using `initramfs-tools`.  I'd be okay with assigning a static IP address for the initramfs, but I can't find how to set that either.  I saw in the manual page `initramfs-tools(8)` the `ip` parameter, but I don't know where to specify it.

Update: `ip` is not being passed as a kernel command line parameter:

```
cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.16-3-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/root-root_vol ro root=/dev/mapper/root-root_vol ro rootdelay=10
```

I watched it boot and the dhcp is definitely happening after the initramfs starts.

Answer (score 2):

That IP parameter is actually a kernel parameter, given by your bootloader.  If you're seeing the kernel attempt autoconfiguration, there's either already one specified or your kernel has been built with a default to try autoconfiguration.

Try removing the "ip" kernel parameter or specifying "ip=none" and see if that does what you want.  That should be good for relatively modern kernels.

That said, initramfs-tools can pick up behavior from other installed packages.  If the above doesn't disable DHCP, see if there's anything plugged in there by your DHCP client packages.